# Python script to encrypt a message fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, hmac

Trying to encrypt to HMAC-SHA256 by giving my script a key and message.

A popular example that I saw online fails to run on my machine:

```
import hmac
import hashlib
import binascii

def create_sha256_signature(key, message):
    byte_key = binascii.unhexlify(key)
    message = message.encode()
    enc = hmac.new(byte_key, message, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest().upper()
    print (enc)

create_sha256_signature("KeepMySecret", "aaaaa")
```

why am I getting this error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "encryption.py", line 12, in <module>
    create_sha256_signature("SaveMyScret", "aaaaa")
  File "encryption.py", line 8, in create_sha256_signature
    byte_key = binascii.unhexlify(key)
binascii.Error: Odd-length string
```

How should I change my code so I will be able to give my own short key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `unhexlify` it implies that your `key` is a hexadecimal representation of bytes. E.g. `A73FB0FF...`. In this kind of encoding, every character represents just 4 bits and therefore you need two characters for a byte and an even number of characters for the whole input string.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html):

> hexstr must contain an even number of hexadecimal digits

But actually the given secrets "SaveMySecret" or "KeepMySecret have not only a odd number of characters, but are not even valid hex code, so it would fail anyway with:

> binascii.Error: Non-hexadecimal digit found

You can either provide a key in hex encoded form, or instead of calling `unhexlify` use something like

```
byte_key = key.encode('utf-8')
```

to get bytes as input for `hmac.new()`

Comment: This works but now the output is all uppercase. I expected it to be lowercase as typically.. Didn't want to use lower() function.

Comment: The `.upper()` makes it uppercase, so just remove that.

Comment: Didn't put attention to the upper(). Thanks a lot!